# Unity Black & White Material How to Change the color individual color (Black & White)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a material with a jpg on it, so the whole thing is black and white. Is there a way to change the Black parts to any color and then change the white parts to any color?

So the Black and white material could be any two colors like red and blue etc.?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is to use one channel of your texture to lerp between two other colours. This does mean that greys will come out as a colour half way between the two colours you select, which may not always be desirable.

Here's a simple Diffuse surface shader that uses this approach. You could create similar shaders for other purposes, such as UI.

Just put this shader in your project, modify your texture to be red and green, then apply this shader to the material you use to render the texture. You can then modify the properties on the material to modify what colour the two colours are rendered as.

```c
Shader "Custom/Recolourable" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _BlackColor ("Black Color", Color) = (0,0,0,1)
    _WhiteColor ("White Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 150
    Cull Off

CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert noforwardadd

sampler2D _MainTex;
fixed4 _BlackColor;
fixed4 _WhiteColor;

struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex;
};

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
    o.Albedo = lerp(_BlackColor, _WhiteColor, c.r);
    o.Alpha = c.a;
}
ENDCG
}

Fallback "Mobile/VertexLit"
}
```

Comment: I am starting to understand this code, but not quite sure how I would change only black or white to a certain RGB value through C# to this file @eAi

Comment: @user3277468: I've edited my answer to do this (the code isn't tested, but probably works!)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting TOK_SHADER